# Sqlite Unable to open the database file using JDBC

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I am traversing a json file, and form querys to store data into the database at the same time. The following code will be run for each record of the json file.

```
String batch="xxxxxx";//this will be my query
try (Connection conn = this.connect();
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement())
    {

        stmt.addBatch(batch);
        stmt.executeBatch();
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

However, it raises error after processing 800,000 lines.

> [SQLITE_CANTOPEN] Unable to open the database file ( unable to open database file )

I am using the same database the entire process.

Anyideas?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: You might want to try refactoring your code to use a single connection for the entire operation instead of open and closing a connection for each individual statement. Also, using `addBatch` immediately followed by `executeBatch` just adds unnecessary overhead when you could just do `executeUpdate`.